# Using hamburger menu breaks NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm learning SwiftUI. I have an app that have 3 other pages (about, request, supported apps). I wanna show them on the top. When I use HStack, navigation link works but it's ugly to show lots of navlinks on the top. So when I add hamburger menu to hide items, you can click the menu items but navigation link doesn't forwards you to page anymore.

I cleared Vstack to simplify the code since it's not relevant. This version works:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {}
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: About()) {
                        Text("About")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: AppList()) {
                        Text("Supported Apps")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: Request()) {
                        Text("Request")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingShareSheet) {
        ActivityView(activityItems: [self.cleanedURL])
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showBuyMeACoffeePopup) {
        BuyMeACoffee (isPresented: $showBuyMeACoffeePopup)
    }
    .onAppear {
        Task {
            globalSpecialHosts = await fetchSpecialHosts()
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't working:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {}
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Menu {
                    NavigationLink(destination: About()) {
                        Text("About")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: AppList()) {
                        Text("Supported Apps")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: Request()) {
                        Text("Request")
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingShareSheet) {
        ActivityView(activityItems: [self.cleanedURL])
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showBuyMeACoffeePopup) {
        BuyMeACoffee(isPresented: $showBuyMeACoffeePopup)
    }
    .onAppear {
        Task {
            globalSpecialHosts = await fetchSpecialHosts()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which iOS version you are building for but as per the latest update it's best to use `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView`. That should fix the Navigation issue you are having. Here's a simple example of the hamburger menu for you to test out.

```
struct ContentView: View  {
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {}
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Menu {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("About Page")) {
                            Text("About")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Supported Page")) {
                            Text("Supported Apps")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Request Page")) {
                            Text("Request")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Menu", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes NavigationStack fixes the issue! Thanks a lot. But I'm targeting iOS 14 or higher and this only works for iOS16 or higher which is a bit too restrictive I think. Are there any other ways to overcome this issue? It's weird that simple menu to break things but I'm not that familiar with Swift. @Yasha

Comment: Swift and SwiftUI have changed quite a lot in recent days. If you want to support older versions, the only safe way I can think of would be something like this.

    `struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            #if swift(>=5.5)
            if #available(iOS 16, *) {
                ContentViewForIOS16AndAbove()
            } else {
                ContentViewForBelowIOS16()
            }
            #else
            ContentViewForBelowIOS16()
            #endif
        }
    }`

Comment: I don't think making a simple code with multiple views just for a hamburger menu is nice to have but I'll try it anyways. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still don't know why, but using menu breaks `NavigationLink`.

Two approaches to fix:

1- Using `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView`. But this approach needs iOS 16 or higher.

2- A workaround. Both hamburger menu and `NavigationLink` works for iOS 14. Here is my code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedOption: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {}
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Menu {
                            Button("About") {
                                selectedOption = "About"
                            }
                            Button("Supported Apps") {
                                selectedOption = "Apps"
                            }
                            Button("Request") {
                                selectedOption = "Request"
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Label("Menu", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3")
                        }
                    }
                }
            // Invisible NavigationLinks
            NavigationLink(destination: About(), tag: "About", selection: $selectedOption) { EmptyView() }
            NavigationLink(destination: AppList(), tag: "Apps", selection: $selectedOption) { EmptyView() }
            NavigationLink(destination: Request(), tag: "Request", selection: $selectedOption) { EmptyView() }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingShareSheet) {
            ActivityView(activityItems: [self.cleanedURL])
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showBuyMeACoffeePopup) {
            BuyMeACoffee(isPresented: $showBuyMeACoffeePopup)
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                globalSpecialHosts = await fetchSpecialHosts()
            }
        }
    }
}
```